# How to send push notifications without OneSignal Dashboard?

Tags: java, android, push-notification, onesignal

I want to send push notifications to all devices where my apk is installed, I follow this tutorial :

> https://rasupe.com/cara-membuat-push-notifications-di-android-dengan-onesignal-mudah/

and successful.

but I want to send push notifications without via OneSignal dashboard website. 
I don't know how to implement it to the codes.

could you please help me..

Comment: check the onesignal API documentation.

Comment: already check there but im really sad, sir. that I dont get it *crying TnT

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a https POST request using Url https://onesignal.com/api/v1/notifications

Add Headers `"Content-Type":"application/json"` and `"Authorization":"Enter your REST API Key here"`

In Body add

```
{
    "app_id": "Enter your app id here",
    "headings": {
        "en": "Title Here"
    },
    "contents": {
        "en": "Description Here"
    },
    "included_segments":["Active Users"]
}
```

You can send the notifications to particular segments and create filters for users and much more, refer this documentation for more info 
https://documentation.onesignal.com/reference

Comment: How to make a POST request to https://onesignal.com/api/v1/notifications??

Comment: Are you not making any network request in your app? If no then you can  explore how to make network request using popular libraries like **Loopj** , **Retrofit** or **volley**.

Comment: I use retrofit library. I follow this tutorial too.. then how?

Comment: cannot understand the issue you are facing, can you be more specific.

Comment: I got successful send notifications with your solution by Postman sir, thank you.. 
but how to implement it to android.. with condition (if there is "input data" to database, then everybody get push notification). 
I follow this tutorial : https://www.codepolitan.com/rest-api-client-sederhana-dengan-retrofit-pada-android-studio-58986d62c46ae for input data, update data, delete data, view data in MySQL database.

Comment: https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/sending-data-with-retrofit-2-http-client-for-android--cms-27845 refer this

Comment: where and what codes i shoud add to my project? ini php or java class?

Comment: you have to make post request with specified headers and body when you want to get the notification, generally notifications are handled on the server side, i don't have idea about that.

Comment: i am glad to know that you were able to solve the issue, happy coding.

Answer (score 0):

To send notification without the OneSignal dashboard,  you can attach tags to users and send notifications to them by making a POST using the URL https://onesignal.com/api/v1/notifications

Segments can be created only by using the OneSignal dashboard, but tags can be created by using the SDK/API.

Add Headers `"Content-Type":"application/json"` and `"Authorization":"Basic <REST API Key>"`

In body add

```
        {
   "app_id":"<App Id>",
   "headings":{
      "en":"Title Here"
   },
   "contents":{
      "en":"Description Here"
   },
   "filters":[
      {
         "field":"tag",
         "key":"level",
         "relation":"=",
         "value":"10"
      },
      {
         "operator":"OR"
      },
      {
         "field":"amount_spent",
         "relation":">",
         "value":"0"
      }
   ]
}
```

Then make a JSON object request to complete the process.

You can refer the following code to see how to attach headers to a JSON object request & to attach tags to your users. (This request has been made by using android volley)

```
  String url = "https://onesignal.com/api/v1/notifications";

                JSONObject jsonBody;
                try {
                    jsonBody = new JSONObject(
                            "{'app_id':'app-id'," +
                            "'headings': {'en': 'title'}, " +
                            "'contents': {'en': 'message'}," +
                                    "'filters':[{'field':'tag','key':'"+id+"','relation':'=','value':'true'}]}"
                    );

                //request a json object response
                JsonObjectRequest jsonRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, jsonBody, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                        //now handle the response
                        Toast.makeText(Activity.this,  "Notification successfully sent", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        //handle the error
                        Toast.makeText(Activity.this, "An error occurred", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        error.printStackTrace();
                    }
                })
                {    //adding header to the request
                    @Override
                    public Map<String, String> getHeaders() {
                        Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                        params.put("Authorization", "Basic <REST API KEY>");
                        params.put("Content-type", "application/json");
                        return params;
                    }
                };
                // Add the request to the queue
                Volley.newRequestQueue(Activity.this).add(jsonRequest);
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
```

Attaching tags to a user

```
 JSONObject tags = new JSONObject();
            try {
                tags.put("key","value");
                //for the above JSON request I have used the following key value pair
                // tags.put(id,true);  
                // where id is a string containing the userId
                //true is a boolean value
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            OneSignal.sendTags(tags);
```

This should successfully complete your query.